# Dynamically add text to the bottom of a div and scroll with text in focus

Tags: javascript, logging, mootools

I have a script that currently displays status messages from a series of functions using FireBug console logs, I want to display those log messages in a single div as have them appear the same way they do in FireBug.

That is the most recent at the bottom and the div will automaticly scroll-down with each new line beyond the height of the div. A log window.

Am using JS Lib - Mootools 1.4.5

Thanks.

Comment: check notimoo or moogrowl or any other growler.

Comment: :/ not what im looking for at all. I need more like a log window than notifications popups.

Comment: @DimitarChristoff, normal firebug for firefox.

Comment: @DimitarChristoff http://getfirebug.com/logging

Comment: no, i mean - get firebug lite.

Comment: Why? I dont want to use Firebug, im using firebug as an example of how I want the logging div to function.

Comment: Have a look at tornLog : https://github.com/fyrye/tornLog/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do it.

```
var log = 'This is awesome log';

function updateLog(logText)
{
    // update logContainer
    var logContainer = $('.logContainer');
    logContainer.set('html', logContainer.get('html') + '<br>' + logText);

    // scroll logContainer to the bottom
    logContainer.scrollTop = logContainer.scrollHeight;
}

updateLog(log);
```